# SQL Server 2008 - Remote connection failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, remote-access

I got a very large search. But did not answer.

I did the following settings :

```
1. I enabled SQL Browser
2. I enabled TCP/IP and set port 1433
3. I turned off my Firewall
4. In SQL Managment studio , I added a new user and set owner;
5. In sql Managment studio , I checked: allow remote connection
6. I used SQL Server and Windows security mode
```

But I still can't connect remotely.

Comment: Please show us your connection string or connection parameters. Try to use IP address instead of server name.

Comment: 192.168.1.104\sqlexpress,1433: in sql managment studio i use this address  
but it doesn't work

Comment: Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager. Right-click on SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration and choose Properties. What is the current setting for Force Protocol Encryption?

Comment: force protocol encyption is "No"

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking network connectivity with `ping`.

If that works, you can very that the socket is accessible and listening with `telnet`.

Comment: i used this command : telnet 192.168.1.104 1433    but not working